Wrong way to find $a$ if remainder of $25!/(23!-a)$ is $3600$?
The question is: $a$ is a single-digit number, and the remainder from $25!/(23!-a)$ is $3600$. What is $a$?
(Source: A problem in Turkish university acceptance exam (AYT).)
Some guy on Reddit claimed that he found the solution to this by $3600/(25!/23!)=6$, which is the correct answer.
This made no sense to me, so I tried to do the same with other factorial numbers, for example $13!/(10!-5)$, the remainder is $8580$, and if you divide it by $13\cdot12\cdot11$ it gives $5$, but, if I try doing this with something like $13!/(8!-5)$ the remainder is $6215$ and you cannot divide it by $13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9$.
Why does this work with some numbers and it doesn't with others? I'm curious; this probably has some simple explanation.
Also, people say they solved this question using polynomials, and I would like to know how that is done. I solved it by doing the following:
$25!-3600=(23!-a)$, $25(24!-12^2)=(23!-a)\cdot x$,
$25(24(23!-6))=(23!-a)x$,
$a=6$.

This is your first time here. Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

$13\times12\times11\times10\times9=154440>40320=8!$; indeed $13!=(8!-5)(154440)+772200$, and $772200$ is $5\times154440$, but the remainder $6215$ is less than $772200$ since $772200>8!-5$

What is AYT ? Please don't use acrononyms that are unknown outside a small circle of initiated people.

J. W. Tanner's response is not clear enough for me and I didn't get where he is going, can anybody else explain ?
AYT is Turkiye's university acceptance exam

We have $$\frac{25!-3600}{23!-a}=\frac{600\times23!-3600}{23!-a}=\frac{600(23!-6)}{23!-a}$$ This value should be an integer $A$. If we take the immediate possibility $(a,A)=(6,600)$ the equality is verified. In fact, we have the equality
$$\frac{25!}{23!-6}=600+\frac{3600}{23!-6}$$

This is how I solved the question as stated in the post. Is there any other solutions ?

@cekos: I didn't see your solution, I am sorry. What I remember is to have try several ways before my answer looking your problem as a diophantine equation with large coefficients difficult to manipulate. I apologize.

There are actually $1792=7\times2^8$ possible values for $\ a\ $ (assuming that $\ 23!-a\ $ must be positive). The remainder of $25!$ on division by $\ 23!-a\ $ will be $3600$ if and only if $\ 23!-a>3600\ $ and
$$
25!=m(23!-a)+3600
$$
for some positive integer $\ m\ ,$ or, equivalently,
\begin{align}
m(23!-a)&=25!-3600\\
&=2^43^25^2\cdot29027\cdot177269\cdot837352324673\ .
\end{align}
This will be satisfied if and only if $\ 23!-a\ $ is one of the $7\times2^8$ factors of $25!-3600$ that are greater than $3600$ and $\ m\ $ is the complementary factor.
The factors of $25!-3600$ that exceed $3600$ are exactly those that include one or more of $29027,177269$, or $837352324673$ as one of their factors, and there are exactly $7\times2^8$ such factors of $25!-3600$.
Addendum
With the additional information that $\ a\ $ must be a single-digit number, we must have
$$
\frac{25!-3600}{23!+9}\le m\le\frac{25!-3600}{23!-9}\ ,
$$
and since $\ \frac{25!-3600}{23!+9}\ $ and $\ \frac{25!-3600}{23!-9}\ $ both differ from $600$ by a minuscule fraction, this must be the only integer in the range between those two numbers.  Therefore
\begin{align}
23!-a&=\frac{25!-3600}{600}\\
&=23!-6\ ,
\end{align}
and $\ a=6\ $ is the only single-digit solution.

I looked at the question again and it states that $a$ is a single digit number

Let's take the general form of the question: given three integers $n,m,y \in \mathbb{N}_0$, find $x\in\mathbb{N}_0$ s.t. $y<(n!-x)$ and $$(n+m)! \equiv y \mod (n! - x)$$
Here we want to find the constraints on $n,m,x$ s.t. one solution to the above problem is $$x= y\cdot\frac{n!}{(n+m)!}$$
One obvious constraint we get is from $$\begin{split}
y&<(n!-x)\\
x\cdot\frac{(n+m)!}{n!}&<n!-x\\
x\left(1 + \frac{(n+m)!}{n!}\right)&<n!
\end{split}$$
Your example of $13!/(8!-5)$ doesn't satisfy this, and hence fails.
The second condition that $(n+m)!-x\cdot\frac{(n+m)!}{n!}$ is divisible by $n!-x$, doesn't produce any further constraint on $n,m,x$.
So you should be able to use the above formula $x= y\cdot\frac{n!}{(n+m)!}$ for this type of problem as long as the above constraint is satisfied (and $y\cdot\frac{n!}{(n+m)!} \in \mathbb{N}_0$)

Also not sure of any polynomial way of solving this, whatever that means
